# Can anyone help me to find this rock music?

Tags: lyrics, rock

Some years ago, maybe more than 10, when I was a kid, I used to listen to a very engaging rock music that i’m mad to try to find what that music was. I remember some part of the lyrics but they aren’t correct, as i can’t find it on google. The part i remember it’s something equivalent to the following:

"And the cats and the rain and the thunderstorm (...) like you babe" or “and the cats and the rain and the thunder sound (...) lime you babe”

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Duarte. Can you offer any more information about the song? Maybe the instruments you remember? Whether it was fast or slow? High or low voice? Questions that don't provide enough information risk being closed.

Answer (score 3):

sounds like "Cats In The Cradle" to me, most popular version from Ugly Kid Joe:

Comment: That’s it! Thanks a lot! Incredible you just made my day :-) i’ll just put it looping and listen to the music

Comment: if this is the right answer, you can accept it.....